# Azure BlobBatchClient.DeleteBlobsAsync always return 404 blob not found

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am experiencing a very strange behaviour when trying to do a batch delete blobs in a container. Having the following code (note some of the code is omitted or edited for brevity and security reasons):

```
var blobServiceClient = GetAzureBlobServiceClient();
var container = await BuildAzureContainer(blobServiceClient);

var blobsToBeDeleted = new List<Uri>();

var thumbImage = removedMedia.Path.GetThumbImageName();
blobsToBeDeleted.Add(new Uri("https://account-name.blob.core.windows.net/container-name/blob-name"));

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(thumbImage))
{
    blobsToBeDeleted.Add(new Uri("https://account-name.blob.core.windows.net/container-name/thumbs/blob-name"));
}

if (blobsToBeDeleted.Any())
{
    var batch = blobServiceClient.GetBlobBatchClient();
    await batch.DeleteBlobsAsync(blobsToBeDeleted, DeleteSnapshotsOption.IncludeSnapshots);
}
```

Using `Azure.Storage.Blobs`(12.9.0) and `Azure.Storage.Blobs.Batch`(12.6.0)
Right before I try to do the batch delete I am uploading the images to Azure and confirming they are uploaded and exist in the container. The response from Azure is:

```
System.AggregateException: 2 batch operation(s) failed. (The specified blob does not 
exist.
RequestId: **removed**
Time:2021-06-18T08:16:15.2409894Z
Status: 404 (The specified blob does not exist.)
ErrorCode: BlobNotFound
```

Tried also to get the Uri using:

```
container.GetBlobClient("blob-name").Uri
```

or

```
container.GetBlobClient("thumbs/blob-name}").Uri
```

which also returns a correct url but with no luck.

I have checked and the URLs I am adding to the list are exactly the same with the active ones in Azure. No matter what I am doing the response is the same - all batch operations return `BlobNotFound`. For instance if do the following with the same blob:

```
BlobClient blob = container.GetBlobClient("container-name/blob-name");
await blob.DeleteAsync(DeleteSnapshotsOption.IncludeSnapshots);
```

The blob is successfully deleted. I am really struggling with this and cannot find what is causing this behaviour especially when I am able to delete the same blob but not in a batch. Am I missing something or there's something happening with the SDK?
Decided to write here before opening a new issue in GitHub.

Any help would be really appreciated.

P.S. I am sure this was working a couple of months ago and the only thing changed is NuGet package updates.

Comment: I just raised an issue here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/24093.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some tests on my side, if you specify `DeleteSnapshotsOption.IncludeSnapshots` for `batch.DeleteBlobsAsync` to delete blobs that have no snapshot, you will get a 404 error.

So I am afraid you need to check if blobs have snapshots or not before deleting them by batch.

Comment: You are so right. Didn't think this would case the issue. Just tested and confirm - if no snapshots are available, DeleteBlobsAsync() should be called without DeleteSnapshotsOption.IncludeSnapshots

Comment: Interesting! So I tried the same and I was able to delete blobs in batch regardless of whether they have snapshots or not. My code was using Node SDK though. I will try the same with .Net SDK.